# How to page up/down in PyCharm's Python console?

Tags: pycharm

In PyCharm's Python console, how can I page up or down in the output using only the keyboard?  The page up/down keys have no effect, neither do the other bindings I have (ctrl-v/meta-v).  Up and down arrows, of course, just go through my command history, they do not scroll the window.  Scrolling with the mouse works, but I would love not to have to reach for the rat.  Thanks!

OS X 10.11.3, PyCharm 5.0.4, Python 2.7.10 with IPython 4.1.1 in the console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JetBrains says, "Unfortunately it's not possible to scroll console output without mouse."  I filed [an enhancement request to add keyboard scrolling in the Python console](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18640).

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately this hasn't been enhanced yet.